# How to set #string into value having the same regex in karate

Tags: regex, xml, karate, gherkin

I am trying to set #string into value having the same regex in karate, as following:
I have sampleXML:

```
<Addresses>
    <Address Id="AD1">
       <StreetNum>0001</StreetNum>                   
    </Address>
    <Address Id="BR9">
       <StreetNum>0002</StreetNum>                   
    </Address>
    ...
</Addresses>
```

From the above xml example, I will set #string into value having the same regex, as following:

```
* string temp = sampleXML
* xml report = temp.replaceAll('<Address Id="#regex [A-Z0-9]{3}">', '<Address Id="#string">')
```

**But it doesn't work**, so please help me if you know that how to set #string into value having the same regex in karate? Thanks!

My expected result as:

```
<Addresses>
        <Address Id="#string">
           <StreetNum>0001</StreetNum>                   
        </Address>
        <Address Id="#string">
           <StreetNum>0002</StreetNum>                   
        </Address>
        ...
 </Addresses>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is trickier than I thought, you have to use regexes in JavaScript:

```
* text payload =
"""
<Addresses>
    <Address Id="AD1">
       <StreetNum>0001</StreetNum>                   
    </Address>
    <Address Id="BR9">
       <StreetNum>0002</StreetNum>                   
    </Address>
</Addresses>
"""
* def temp = payload.replaceAll(/Id="[^"]+"/g, 'Id="#string"')
* print temp
```

For more advanced needs, you also have the option of calling Java code: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#calling-java

Comment: Yeah, that solved my problem. Thanks Peter for your help!